# Coin tossing: if we flip a coin x times, what's the probability of there being some subset of n flips containing m heads?

Tags: probability, combinatorics

I've been grappling with this one combinatorially, but I'm still not sure I have it, and wanted to see if anyone could provide a nice closed form solution.

Suppose we have a biased coin that lands heads with probability *p* and tails with probability *(1 - p)*. If we flip the coin *x* times, what's the probability that there is some run of *n* consecutive flips in which the coin lands heads *m* times? (The *m* heads need not be consecutive, and obviously *x* ≥ *n* ≥ *m*.)

Sorry if this has already been asked - a brief search didn't turn anything up.

Comment: [Why are you interested in this question, and what did you try?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question) Do you have a solution, even if not a 'nice closed form'?

Comment: Now posted to (but closed on) MO, https://mathoverflow.net/questions/314724/coin-flipping-in-x-flips-of-a-biased-coin-whats-the-probability-that-there-is